# Script works in Adobe Dreamweaver Preview but not on Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, dreamweaver

I have been developing a website over the past couple of days on Adobe Dreamweaver. Below I have some JavaScript that is meant to work when someone scrolls.

It works when I use the link (https://adobe.ly/........). However, when I load the index myself it does not work.

I am unable to find out the reason why.

It's probably something small and stupid and I'm going to pull my hair out because of it.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").classList.add("sticky");
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "20px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.paddingTop = "0px";
    document.getElementById("headertext").style.visibility = "visible";

  }

  if (document.body.scrollTop < 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").classList.remove("sticky");
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "transparent";
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "30px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.paddingTop = "20px";
    document.getElementById("headertext").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

This is my HTML when I link the scripts, at the bottom of the HTML Code.

```
<script src="js/navbarscroll.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script is working for me, check the script src tags in the html.

Try: 
`/js/navbarscroll.js`